# JQuery Mobile selectmenu() multiple option true/false -> not refreshing the displaying of choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Regarding JQuery and JQueryMobile,

Code is in this JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nyluje/jg5cgw76/7/

I use a `flipswitch` to change, if a `select` object has the attribute `multiple` or not.

At first the `flipswitch` is `off` and the attribute `multiple` does not apply on the `select`.

If I use the `select`, I can choose only one single option (this works fine).

Then I turn the `flipswitch` to `on`. Now with the code I implemented in the function `setSelectAccordingToFs()` the attribute `multiple` is added to the `select` and it is then possible to pickup multiple options. But one notices that the `pop-up`, which is not a native menu one, does not display the **multiple select** correctly, like on this picture:

[image: multiple select as it should be]

It **keeps on displaying the single select panel**. Which does allow to add up options, but **does not provide the possibility to take off some**:

[image: multiple select on a single select panel]

Hence I wonder: How to **refresh the select panel menu used by a select**, depending on the `attribute` multiple value:'off' or 'on', on that `select` tag?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I implemented it in this version of my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nyluje/jg5cgw76/8/

**The trick:**
Using the option 'refresh' wasn't enough. To (really) refresh the `selectmenu` **and include the panel in this refresh**, the 'destroy' and 'enable' functionnalities have to be used. So at the bottom of my function setSelectAccordingToFs() I added something like that:

```
    targetSelect.selectmenu('destroy');     
    targetSelect.selectmenu();
    targetSelect.selectmenu('enable');      
    targetSelect.selectmenu('refresh',true);
```